# How to disable an input element based on a certain condition in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, input

I'm creating a grid of input elements based on a numeric array called board. I need to conditionally disable certain elements based on their values. If board[i][j] holds a non-zero value, the corresponding input element should be initially disabled. However, even after entering a non-zero value into a previously non-disabled input element, I don't want any other input elements to be disabled.

here is the code for creating grid of input elements:

```
<mat-grid-list [cols]="cols" rowHeight="50px" gutterSize="5px" rowHeight="1:1">
    @for (row of board; let i = $index; track i) {
        @for (num of row; let j = $index; track j) {
        <mat-grid-tile>
          <input type="number" inputmode="numeric" class="tile" [(ngModel)]="board[i][j]"
            [value]="board[i][j] === 0 ? '' : board[i][j]" 
            disabled="board[i][j] !== 0"
            (keydown)="tileKeyDown($event)">
        </mat-grid-tile>
        }
    }
  </mat-grid-list>
```

`disabled="board[i][j] !== 0"` this is disabling all input elements even if board[i][j] equals zero value.

`[disabled]="board[i][j] !== 0` this working fine till i enter a non-zero value in a non-disabled input elements then they also are getting disabled which i don't want.

How do i make certain input element disabled initially and later no element should be disabled if a value is entered in allowed input elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, instead of binding `disabled` to `board` value I am binding it to `initialBoard` which is a copy of `board` array and this `initialBoard` will never be updated, but I don't like this approach mush as I am creating a copy of my original array.

If anyone else has a better approach, please respond.

This is my final code:

```
<mat-grid-list [cols]="cols" rowHeight="50px" gutterSize="5px" rowHeight="1:1">
    @for (row of board; let i = $index; track i) {
        @for (num of row; let j = $index; track j) {
        <mat-grid-tile>
          <input type="number" inputmode="numeric" class="tile" 
            [value]="board[i][j] === 0 ? '' : board[i][j]" 
            [disabled]="initialBoard[i][j] !== 0"
            (keydown)="tileKeyDown($event)">
        </mat-grid-tile>
        }
    }
  </mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: You could make the board array an array of objects (e.g.: `[{ value: 1, disabled: false }, {value: 0, disabled: true}]` ) and determine the disabled state when initializing the array or component.

Then add an event listener (e.g.: `(change)`) to update/change the disabled property.

This way, you add a little bit of complexity to the board array, but you also add a lot of flexibility. Also you don't have to copy the board array.

Comment: I like this approach, although I won't be using it because I am receiving the board from an API call, and duplicating the board array is simpler for me

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `$index` enumerator as an index into the array. Like this (a simplified code snippet):

```
@for (i of board; let index = $index; track i) {
  <p>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="board[index]" [disabled]="board[index] !== 0">
  </p>
  <hr>
}
```

See a working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-inputs-disable?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: No, this is not working as I want. I also tried it this way. [disabled]="board[index] !== 0" is binding the disabled attribute according to the board value at the index. If later I change the value of the board at that index, the corresponding input element is also getting disabled, which I don't want.

Comment: I understood that your problem was that *other* input elements become disabled when you change an input element value to non-zero

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
[disabled]="board[i][j] !== 0 ? true : null"
```

Comment: No, this will not work. I tried this approach, and @BennyHalperin also suggested it. I don't want to bind 'disabled' to the board's value; I only want to set the input element to be enabled or disabled according to the initial board value.